# how to prove this limit, convolution?

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

I am wondering how to prove that $\vert (f*g)(x) \vert \rightarrow 0 $  when $\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty$ if we assume $f \in L^{p}(\mathbb R)$ and $g \in L^{q}(\mathbb R)$  where $1/p+1/q=1$ with $p>1$. I think that the idea is to use the density of compactly smooth functions in $L^p$ but I have some trouble to find the solution... Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What important theorem has the condition that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$?

Comment: this is a sufficient condition for $f*g$ to exist, with that condition we have $t \mapsto f(x-t)g(t) \in L^{1}$

Comment: Yes, but we have other important theorems involving that as a condition that are useful here. You can use a statement more than once.